# how to get address on drag map pin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocomplete

How can I *get the address using map by dragging* a pin?

**here is the link which I am using the map** : [MAP-ADDRESS](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/draggable.html)

The problem is, when I drag the pin that time latlong is changeable but the address is not.

**javascript code:**

```
$(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
          map: ".map_canvas",
          details: "form",
          markerOptions: {
            draggable: true
          },
          types: ["geocode", "establishment"]
        });

       // I can get lat long from here, but how to get the address?
        $("#geocomplete").bind("geocode:dragged", function(event, latLng){
          $("input[name=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
          $("input[name=lng]").val(latLng.lng());
          $("input[name=formatted_address]").val('address value');         
          $("#reset").show();
        });
        $("#find").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
        });
});
```

Comment: where is your  $("input[name=formatted_address]" ?

Comment: here it is not mentioned, because I can't get the address @Akshaypadwal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    crossdomain: true,
                    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
                    data: {
                        key: 'key',
                        latlng: lat + "," + lng
                    },
                    success: function (json) {
                      //show on page
                    },
                    async: false,
                    error: function ()
                    {
                       console.log()
                    }
                });
```

Comment: @PathikVejani inside your bind function ("#geocomplete").bind("geocode:dragged", function(event, latLng){...

Comment: yes i got your point but that should be any function like `latLng.lat()`